# I was trying to create a music bot with nextcord and wavelink, by seeing a tutorial on youtube, it was text command but im trying to do slash command

Tags: python, discord.py, nextcord

Here's my code for making a music slash command

```
@drav.slash_command(name='play', description='Plays a song', guild_ids=[server])
async def play(interaction: Interaction, song: wavelink.YouTubeTrack):
    await interaction.response.defer(ephemeral=True, with_message=True)
    if not interaction.guild.voice_client:
        vc = wavelink.Player = await interaction.user.voice.channel.connect(cls=wavelink.Player)
    elif not getattr(interaction.user.voice, "channel", None):
        return await interaction.followup.send(embed=nextcord.Embed(title=':x: Join a voice channel yourself first!', color=nextcord.Colour.red()))
    else:
        vc: wavelink.Player = interaction.guild.voice_client

    await vc.play(song)
    await interaction.followup.send(Playing!)
```

It doesn't register my command as I have not specified that the argument song has to be str or int but if I do that where should I type wavelink.YouTubeTrach..... Please Help
I have tried using multiple ways but can't figure it out

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to update your nextcord by using `pip install -U nextcord`. I can register a slash command without specify the type of argument in my slash command.

And lastly, do you select the `application.commands` option when you generate your bot invite link at [discord developer portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications)?

[image]